# Arabic characters showing as question mark in ASP.Net page on production but not on dev

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ascii, arabic

I am reading an Excel file (xlsx) and displaying data on screen. The following code works fine on Dev but not on Production. On production it is displaying ? along with ASCII code 63 for all Arabic characters. On dev it displays correct Arabic character with its ASCII code.
What could be the reason? I thought it is due to Arabic language pack missing from production but even after installing, the error still comes.

There is no read/write from database. Just read Excel and display data on screen.

```
Private Sub CheckChar(ByVal temp As String)
    For i As Integer = 0 To temp.Length - 1
            Response.Write("(char=" & temp.Substring(i, 1) & ")(asc=" & Asc(temp.Substring(i, 1)) & ")<br />")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You need `UTF-8` encoding for Arabic/Hebrew. See the response `ContentEncoding` and `Charset` properties.

Comment: Then why does same code works on Dev and not Prod? It's just one asp.net page.